# Kindle 1.29.0 shows empty content for all books on MacOS

Tags: kindle

All books content are empty. When I select the empty area, I can copy the originally invisible text from kindle and paste it visibly to other programs. It means the text is there but I cannot see it.

I have tried reinstalling the app and rebooted my MacBook, but it doesn't work at all.

What should I do?

[image: empty screen]

Answer (score 0):

The solution is easy.

Open the terminal, enter the following command

```
sudo chmod -x /Applications/Kindle.app/Contents/MacOS/renderer-test
```

Open the Kindle app

Viola!
[image: problem solved]